How to get one face of 3D shape to match the surface of another
I have an STL file of a complex geometry (shoe-like object) and I am trying to create a separate object to fill the inside of that geometry (simulated leg).
I have tried to use the shrinkwrap modifier to fill the geometry, but I am having a fair bit of trouble. Is there a way to assign the object to fill all of and only the internal surface of the geometry? Or any other suggestions of how to do this? I am using the project option currently but I would like the object to sit fully inside the geometry, and all other option only covers a very limited area. Apologies if this has been asked already, let me know if you need more info and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

